# How to remove <b> tags from inside the <div> tags

Tags: php, parsing

I want to remove b tags from inside the div tags

My HTML CODE:

```
<div class="floatLeft">
<b>Match Sequence: </b> 5th Test, Day 2
</div>
```

My php code:

```
$day = $html->find('div[class=floatLeft] ');
echo"$day[0]";
```

My Result:

```
Match Sequence: 5th Test, Day 2
```

But I want to print

```
 5th Test, Day 2
```

Comment: Does the result contain Match sequence within `<b>` tags or just the plaintext?

Comment: Which parser you are using? If Its `Simple HTML Dom`, then use `$day[0]->find('b',0)->outertext = null; echo $day[0];`

Comment: Please post the complete PHP code, from the initialization of the parser to the echo.

Comment: $("b").remove(); `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them by matching the HTML tags and replacing everything in between with nothing

For Example:

```
$str = "<b>Match Sequence: </b> 5th Test, Day 2";
$newstr = preg_replace('/\<b\>.*\<\/b\>/','',$str);
echo "Old: $str" . PHP_EOL;
echo "New: $newstr" . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
Old: <b>Match Sequence: </b> 5th Test, Day 2
New:  5th Test, Day 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
$str="closing bold tag"; 
echo substr($day[0],strpos($day[0],$str));
```

Comment: I know how strpos work, actually i m new to stackoverflow I didn't notice that closing bold tag is not appearing in my result.

Comment: ahh looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

use strreplace() to replace the  tags (or anything else you would want to replace) with " "

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php